# Bookmarklet not finding input box

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have made a bookmarklet that should highlight the password and username box on a webpage.  It finds the password box, and seems to be locating the text box that is before it, but then it stops working.  Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:var boxes= $(':text, :password');var selectionBox = $(':password'); selectionBox.css('background','red');for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length;i++){alert('loop');if(boxes[i] == selectionBox[0]){alert('Username box found');boxes[i-1].css('background','blue');alert('Success!');}}">Password box highlighter</a>
</body>
```

I get an alert box saying 'loop' a couple of times, then 'Username box found', but then it stops working on the next line, and no 'Success!' alert box.  Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

EDIT:
Here is the code spread out:

```
var boxes= $(':text, :password');
var selectionBox = $(':password');
selectionBox.css('background','red');
for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length;i++){
 alert('loop');
 if(boxes[i] == selectionBox[0]){
  alert('Username box found');
  boxes[i-1].css('background','blue');
  alert('Success!');
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you think we are supposed to debug the code packed in one line like this?

Comment: @Riateche Sorry but it has to be on one line as it is a bookmarklet.

Comment: Can we some HTML, here is a fiddle with your current js code, much easier to read on multiple lines: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/JAb2f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `boxes[i-1]` (which is the same as using `.get(i-1)`) to get a DOM element from the jQuery collection. Try using `.eq()`:

```
boxes.eq(i-1).css('background','blue');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/HsDCs/3/

If you checked your browser's console, you would've seen that it was complaining that `css` isn't a property/method for that element.

References:

- `.eq()`: http://api.jquery.com/eq/
- `.get()`: http://api.jquery.com/get/